# Mac Terminal Cursor Position More Visible

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to change the cursor in terminal to be more readable, since I have a black background and white text.

I have looked at a bunch of posts on this and it doesn't seem possible, especially since I don't want to change the text color, just the cursor color.

I'm on OSX Mavericks, using TotalTerminal. Here is a screen shot of me hovering over a character of text which is hard to see

[image: Terminal Cursor Hard to See]

I found some stuff in the Terminal.plist but I changing them doesn't seem to be doing anything

[image: terminal plist cursor]

Comment: Did you try changing the CursorColor attribute for the theme you're using, and then restart TotalTerminal? The screenshot in your question shows changing the 'Grass' theme, but that theme has a green background and you say you have a black background.

Comment: Ah, wow, it was in total terminal preferences and I missed it. Thanks for the help anyways! Out of curiosity, do you know the format they are using for cursor color? How would I change it in the plist? It was quite a long string of what appears to be hex.